# Distribute software without license

Tags: licensing, copyright, closed-source

I wrote a small tool for a game which I now want to present and distribute in the games official forum.

Since a few days I'm thinking about which license I should use to distribute my program.
I don't want to make it open source and I also don't want to make the licensing a huge topic (the license would probably be bigger than the program itself).

I just want to put it in the forum and give other players the opportunity to use it.

Now I wonder if I need a license at all or if the copyright which I already have is enough.

People should just be allowed to download and use the tool but not redistribute, reverse engineer or modify it. (Actually I'd not even care if they reverse engineer and modify it for personal use.)

Unlike stated in [What is the "default" software license?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26548/what-is-the-default-software-license) I don't plan to `upload my code to github and announce it as a free download / contribute at will`.

Comment: I'm not sure why your edit matters.

Comment: If you don't put a license on it, then they won't be allowed to download and use it, at least in some jurisdictions, because both downloading it and using it involve copying and copying is reserved to the copyright holder by default.